# Multiple API clients get concurrency conflict on auth

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have multiple API clients that call TokenAuth/Authenticate to get an accesstoken for using the API. When they try this too close to eachother I get a concurrency conflict at GetLoginResultAsync in TokenAuthController/Autheticate.

Full exception message: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Why, and how should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I guess your different clients use the same account to login.)

Generally the exception explains; an entity is fetched from database and after that another client fetched the same entity. The second client updated entity and committed to database. While the first client tries to save the entity, he has an outdated dirty entity. Thus you got Concurrency Conflict!

This occurs when [Optimistic Locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_locking) is used. And AspnetBoilerplate uses that method for performance priority against [Pessimistic Locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(database)).

Solution:
In your TokenAuthController class modify Authenticate method ;

```
private static AsyncLock _asyncLock = new AsyncLock();

[HttpPost]
public async Task<AuthenticateResultModel> Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateModel model)
{
    //i am using AsyncLock because there are async methods in Authenticate.
    using (await _asyncLock.LockAsync())
    {
        var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(
            model.UserNameOrEmailAddress,
            model.Password,
            GetTenancyNameOrNull()
        );
        
        //other codes ...
    }
}
```

For AsyncLock library see https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx